# How can I resolve that issue?

Tags: model-view-controller

IDescribableEntity not founds

[image]

My requirement is to maintain all logs of sites.
e.g insertion deletion and edition of any field/table in database must be save in log data i try above code in my project but some thing is missing.

Comment: please do not put a screenshot but paste your code here and update the title of the question

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot to add a `use`.

```
use TheNameSpaceNameWhereYouCreatedTheInterface.IDescribableEntity;
```